# What is causing me to not see output on Flask "hello world" app?

Tags: flask

So I'm just trying to get a basic Hello World app to work for Flask and so far the server has been running but I haven't been able to see the output.

I tried allowing the IP on admin privileges; that's about all I did try. I realize this may just be a case of me being completely idiotic and missing something entirely but please bear with me thanks.

```
#Simple 'hello world' Flask application
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/')


def index():
    return 'Hello World!'


#Use __main__ method 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So the server shows as "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/" but attempts to access that give a "Not Found" error in the browser and a "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404" error in the server output.
I'm supposed to see a "Hello World" output in the browser. The only thing I got to work is the server which shows as up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.route('/')` needs to be `@app.route('/')` . It is an annotator.

Full code below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'


#Use __main__ method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the annotation:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to use app as decorator

```
#Simple 'hello world' Flask application
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'


#Use __main__ method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```